# Ways to show or hide menu without refreshing page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When the user clicks on the Save button I call a method in the controller to save the data:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public JsonNetResult SaveData(MyDataClass data)
{     

    RavenSession.Store(data);
    RavenSession.SaveChanges();
    return new JsonNetResult { Data = data };
}
```

In my asp.net page I get that data and save it in the HttpContext and then on the html page I loop through data I get from Httpcontext and show menu.

```
<ul class="MyMenu" role="menu">
@foreach (var menuItem in HttpContext.MyData())
{
    <li>
        <a href="@Url.Action("MyLoginPage", "Home", new { area = "Home", module = menuItem.Name })">@menuItem .Name
        </a>
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

Everything works OK and I show the menu depending on the data stored in HttpContext. But if data has changed I have to log out of the application and  reload HttpContext and then I get new Menu depending on data.

Is there any technique to show the changed Menu as soon as data changes without having to log out of the application and log back in?

Comment: Have you tried to load partial view in your menu by using AJAX? If no - read about them,

Comment: @AlexanderGroshev could you give me links on what you mean?

Comment: Here is simple tutorial. [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/manas1/sending-partialview-using-jquery-ajax-request-in-Asp-Net-mvc/)

Comment: why are you using HttpContext to store that data here? why not pass that data to the view as a model?  not sure if that make sense to do here.. i'm fairly new to mvc so still learning.. but just trying to understand why HttpContext is used in ur case.

Comment: @psj01 Httpcontext is used in many places and not just showing something in GUI.